# Cant send the text "0880" with .NET SmtpClient.Send()

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient

I bumped on this error while trying to help a developer resolve a bug.
He was having issues with mails that were supposedly send but never arrived. Checking the code and the msg we came to the conclussion that the text that was caousing the issue was "0880". So i made a test page with a button and the following code on it:

```
        SmtpClient cl = new SmtpClient("exchangeserver");
        cl.Send("mail@from.com",
                "mail@to.com",
                "Test",
                "0880");
```

Much to my surprise even thou the Send function executes and doesnt throw an exception the mail never arrives. If i replace the text in the body with other string, say "this is a test mail" the mail arrives fine.
I tried using MailMessage class with the Send() with and without HTML, i even tried using gmail smtp server instead of my company exchange server, but the result its always the same the mail with the 0880 never arrives, all the other strings ive tried do.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: That's bizarre. I wonder what very similar values would do. 1234, 0881, A881, ... things like that.

Comment: Is it getting deleted by a spam filter? Can you see the message in the [tracking logs on your exchange server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124926%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?